# Check_MK - cannot monitor JMX

Tags: java, plugins, jolokia, check-mk

We have `Check_MK` monitoring installed.
The `Check_mk` agent installs automatically when I add a host to the `Check_MK GUI`.

Because of this there is no `main.mk` installed `/etc/check_mk` on the added hosts.

**Question:** Do I have to manually add this??

Also, I would like to monitor a `wildfly server`. The `Jolokia` war file is installed on the host and does give an output through a browser but **how do I then add a plugin such as jar_signature or jolokia_metrics.gc?**

I see very little documentation on the Check_MK website.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

---

Yes, thanks, that was it.

I was incorrectly told that it would be all automatically done from check_mk server. Only the initial install was done but any plugins and baked agent were not. Once I install plugins in usr/lib/check_mk/plugins/ such as jolokia does it all come together. I don't know yet how to use the /local directory yet.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think main.mk is needed on monitored hosts.  It is only needed on the Nagios host.

On the monitored hosts, we need two things:

1. check_mk_agent (scheduled through xinetd)
2. check_mk local check scripts under /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local directory

check_mk_agent performs the standard (built in) checks and then calls the scripts under /usr/lib/check_mk_agent/local one by one, in alphabetical order.  Nagios invokes check_mk_agent by talking to xinetd (which usually listens on port 6557) which in turn invokes check_mk_agent.